# import data to datagrid view

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagrid, addition

i,ve got problem with importing data to my datagridview..
i have 94 data rows which i wanna add to datagridview, but when it comes to 40 datarow i get an error:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
        var result = ia.Rows.Select(
                    r => new
                     {

                         ItemID = r.ItemId,
                         Title = r.Title,
                         Code = r.Code,
                         UnitOfMeasurement = r.UnitOfMeasurement,
                         ItemType = r.ItemType,
                         VatRate = r.VatRate.Name,
                         Price = r.Price,
                         Currency = r.Currency.Name,
                         RevenueAccountDomestic = r.RevenueAccountDomestic.ID,
                         RevenueAccountOutsideEU = r.RevenueAccountOutsideEU.ID,
                         RevenueAccountEU = r.RevenueAccountEU.ID,
                     }).ToList();

            b.DataSource = result;
             dataGridView1.DataSource = b;
```

please if anyone can help me?

this is 40 result:

```
    Code    "#13011"    string
    Currency    {Api.mMApiFkField}  Api.mMApiFkField
    ItemId  2700453 int
    ItemType    "A" string
    Name    null    string
    PageSize    0   long
    Price   0.0 double
    RebatePercent   0.0 double
    RevenueAccountDomestic  null    Api.RevenueAccountDomestic
    RevenueAccountEU    null    Api.RevenueAccountEU
    RevenueAccountOutsideEU null    Api.RevenueAccountOutsideEU
    Rows    null    System.Collections.Generic.List<Api.ItemsPage>
    RowVersion  null    string
    StocksAccount   null    object
    Title   "Plačano po predračunu" string
    UnitOfMeasurement   null    string
    Usage   null    string
    VatRate {Api.mMApiFkField}  Api.mMApiFkField
```

---

And here iz te 1st result which can get to gridview

```
        Code    "#75603"    string
+       Currency    {Api.mMApiFkField}  Api.mMApiFkField
        ItemId  2700454 int
        ItemType    "S" string
        Name    null    string
        PageSize    0   long
        Price   0.46    double
        RebatePercent   0.0 double
+       RevenueAccountDomestic  {Api.RevenueAccountDomestic}    Api.RevenueAccountDomestic
+       RevenueAccountEU    {Api.RevenueAccountEU}  Api.RevenueAccountEU
+       RevenueAccountOutsideEU {Api.RevenueAccountOutsideEU}   Api.RevenueAccountOutsideEU
+       Rows    null    System.Collections.Generic.List<Api.ItemsPage>
        RowVersion  null    string
        StocksAccount   null    object
        Title   "Izdelava etiket"   string
        UnitOfMeasurement   ""  string
        Usage   null    string
+       VatRate {Api.mMApiFkField}  Api.mMApiFkField
```

Comment: chekc 40 datarow value. I hope any one is null or black.

Comment: Make sure your 40th datarow is not empty.

Comment: i add my row result in question if can you look

Comment: RevenueAccountDomestic ,RevenueAccountOutsideEU ,RevenueAccountEU and UnitOfMeasurement is null... That might be a problem...since you are fetching ID from these Api...

Comment: yes its wrong.. thx.. how can i however call data if is it null?

Comment: do anyone know why cant i edit my data in datagridview??  i have set  readonly=false;

Comment: i rying and tryng but i cant do this? can anyone help me please?

Comment: I guess it's because your rows are anonymous type